# expo camera show black screen for first time : React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-camera

I have Created a Project with `expo-camera` which on click of button opens camera. However first time when I click that button only black screen is rendered, after reopening the screen, and  clicking the same button, the Camera UI is rendered on the Screen.

#### Problem

I don't know why it shows black screen first. The Problem only exists in android devices.

[Link to Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@darkkiller/intelligent-blueberries) Try this example on android devices.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  ImageBackground,
  Image,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Entypo, Ionicons, FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Surface, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

let cameraRef;

const PickImage = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [isCameraUiOn, setIsCameraUiOn] = useState(false);
  const [isCapturing, setIsCapturing] = useState(false);
  const [flashMode, setFlashMode] = useState(true);
  const [capturePhoto, setCapturePhoto] = useState(null);  


  const snap = async () => {
    if (cameraRef) {
      let photo = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync({
        quality: 0.5,
      });
      setCapturePhoto(photo.uri);
      setIsCapturing(false);
      setIsCameraUiOn(false);
    }
  };

  const getCameraPermission = async () => {
    const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
    setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  if (isCameraUiOn) {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Camera
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            type={type}
            ref={(ref) => (cameraRef = ref)}
            flashMode={
              flashMode
                ? Camera.Constants.FlashMode.on
                : Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off
            }>
            <Entypo
              name="cross"
              color="#FFF"
              size={50}
              onPress={() => setIsCameraUiOn(false)}
            />
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                alignItems: 'flex-end',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                zIndex: 9999,
              }}>
              <Ionicons
                name="md-reverse-camera"
                color="#FFF"
                size={35}
                onPress={() => {
                  setType(
                    type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                      ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                      : Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  );
                }}
              />
              {isCapturing ? (
                <FontAwesome name="circle" color="#FFF" size={60} />
              ) : (
                <FontAwesome
                  name="circle-o"
                  color="#FFF"
                  size={60}
                  onPress={() => {
                    setIsCapturing(true);
                    snap();
                  }}
                />
              )}
              <Ionicons
                name="ios-flash"
                color={flashMode ? 'gold' : '#FFF'}
                size={35}
                onPress={() => setFlashMode(!flashMode)}
              />
            </View>
          </Camera>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }  else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ margin: 20 }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: '600',
              }}>
              Report Cattles with Ease !!
            </Text>

            <Text
              style={{
                marginVertical: 10,
              }}>
              Our System uses, cloud based fancy image detection algorithm to
              process your image.
            </Text>
          </View>

          <View
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Button
              style={{
                width: width * 0.5,
              }}
              icon="camera"
              mode="contained"
              onPress={() => setIsCameraUiOn(true)}>
              Press me
            </Button>
          </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
};

export default PickImage;
```

[Link to snack Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@darkkiller/intelligent-blueberries)

Answer (score 0):

In case if the black screen is always and you are using android, try to add in your AndroidManifest.xml file .

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue recently. On IOS everything works as expected but on Android screen goes black for the first time and navigating back to it again solves the issue. Here is the reason and fix for it.

**Reason:**
Apparently using expo vector inside the Camera tags causes this issue on Android.

**Solution**
Make your code Platform specific and use View and TouchableOpacity to flip screen or take picture and do not use expo vector for Android.

```
<Camera
    type={type}
    className="flex-1"
    ratio="16:9"
    ref={cameraRef}
>
    <View className="flex-row absolute bottom-10 justify-between w-full px-10">
            {Platform.OS === "android" ? (
                <>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={toggleCameraType}
                        className="bg-white/30 py-2 px-4 rounded-xl"
                    >
                        <Text className="text-white">
                            Flip Camera
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
    
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={clickPicture}
                        className="bg-white/30 py-2 px-4 rounded-xl"
                    >
                        <Text className="text-white">
                            Take Picture
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <Feather
                        name="camera"
                        size={40}
                        color="white"
                        onPress={clickPicture}
                    />
    
                    <Feather
                        name="rotate-ccw"
                        size={40}
                        color="white"
                        onPress={toggleCameraType}
                    />
                </>
            )}
        </View>
    </Camera>
```

Comment: Your code snippet would be more helpful if it reflected changes to the code snippet provided by the original question. For example, remove the `<Feather>` components and replace with something that was referenced in the original code

Answer (score -3):

im with the same problem rn, some people suggested asking for permission before rendering